# None of errors are showing in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

The error messages was showing before on the header section, But now it is not showing.
Can someone help me out...

```
@if(session()->has('message'))

     {{ session()->get('message') }}
@endif
```

Comment: Welcome. You mean validation errors or regular messages? How do you invoke them?

Comment: Did you upgrade to another Laravel version or what happened in between it working and not working?

Comment: The code you show is looking for messages in the session; what errors are you referring to?  [Maybe validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#working-with-error-messages)?

Comment: It is validation errors

Comment: Break the server side validations you will get the errors.

Comment: normally they would be under the key `errors`

Comment: So the link to the docs I included should answer your question ... ?

Comment: if you're using validation errors and it's may inside errors variable not in session.

Comment: Welcome. Did you pass message from controller with blade

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you are talking about validation error.

```
@if($errors->has())
   @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
      <div>{{ $error }}</div>
  @endforeach
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try this if you asking for line by line error

@if($errors->has('name'))
      <div>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</div>
@endif

or if you are asking for session message pass from controller like this

return session()->flash('message','data save successfully');
then you get this message in view like below code.

@if(session()->has('message'))

     {{ session()->get('message') }}
@endif
```

Comment: Welcome, Pankaj

Answer (score 0):

We are checking message in session, first we have to pass in the session and then we can access session data.

This is your blade code for example in you header.blade
@if(Session::has('message'))
    
        
            ×
        
        {{ session('message') }}
    
@endif

From your controller, you have to pass like this 
return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Customer added successfully');

Answer (score 0):

We are checking message in session, first we have to pass in the session and then we can access session data.

This is your blade code for example in you header.blade

```
@if(Session::has('message'))
    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible">
        <button id="session-message-button" type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        {{ session('message') }}
    </div>
@endif
```

From your controller, you have to pass like this

```
return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Customer added successfully');
```